# Javascript sort array of objects using nested attributes where some attributes are undefined

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to implement a sorting function that takes in an array of objects and sorts them by an attribute or a nested attribute. I've looked at a ton of questions on here with good answers to this problem, but so far as I have seen, none of them account for when a nested attribute is missing.

For example, if I sort by `some_attribute` and `some_attribute = undefined` for one of my array elements, the element in question is bumped to the end/beginning of the array, as I would expect. If I sort by `some_attribute.something_else`, the functions I've seen don't respond well when `some_attribute.something_else = undefined`.

Here is a sample of my data structure I'm trying to sort:

```
results = [
    {
        id: 233,
        post: "Test 944 AM http://frmply.co/1mA9G3L",
        twitter_favorite_count: 0,
        twitter_retweet_count: 2,
        twitter_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 3
        },
        twitter_last_updated: "2015-12-28T21:11:27.425Z",
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: 1,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 1
        },
        facebook_last_updated: "2015-12-28T21:11:29.232Z",
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 0
        },
        linkedin_last_updated: "2015-12-28T21:11:29.905Z"
    },
    {
        id: 232,
        post: "Test 944 AM http://frmply.co/1mA9G3L",
        twitter_favorite_count: null,
        twitter_retweet_count: null,
        twitter_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 5
        },
        twitter_last_updated: null,
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: null,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: { },
        facebook_last_updated: null,
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: { },
        linkedin_last_updated: null
    },
    {
        id: 234,
        post: "localhost test 1106am http://frmply.co/1RAYalE",
        twitter_favorite_count: 0,
        twitter_retweet_count: 0,
        twitter_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 2
        },
        twitter_last_updated: "2016-01-06T18:40:21.388Z",
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: null,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 0
        },
        facebook_last_updated: "2015-12-29T16:07:39.042Z",
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 0
        },
        linkedin_last_updated: "2015-12-29T16:07:39.489Z"
    },
    {
        id: 231,
        post: "test",
        twitter_favorite_count: null,
        twitter_retweet_count: null,
        twitter_link_click_count: { },
        twitter_last_updated: null,
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: null,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: { },
        facebook_last_updated: null,
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: { },
        linkedin_last_updated: null
    }
]
```

Now if I run the code below I get `[2, 3, 5, undefined]` as a result when I would expect `[undefined, 2, 3, 5]`.

```
results.sortBy('twitter_link_click_count.total').map(function(x){return x.twitter_link_click_count.total})
```

In the snippet above, `sortBy` is a function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31106445/4139179), however I've also tried using Underscore's `_.sortBy` function with identical results.

**Working Code**

Here is the solution I came up with based off Oleg's answer:

```
var sortKey = attribute.split('.');
var sortBy = function(results, sortKey) {
    return _.sortBy(results, function(item) {
        if(sortKey.length === 1) {
            return item[sortKey[0]] || 0;
        } else {
            return item[sortKey[0]][sortKey[1]] || 0;
        };
    });
};
```

The key difference here is that it generates a `sortKey` array, which can be used an an if/else statement or iterated over. I used an if/else since my `sortKey` is only ever 1 or 2 layers deep inside my object. I also handled cases where my attribute is `null` by returning `0` instead of `true`. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following script (used Underscore there):

```js
results = [
    {
        id: 233,
        post: "Test 944 AM http://frmply.co/1mA9G3L",
        twitter_favorite_count: 0,
        twitter_retweet_count: 2,
        twitter_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 3
        },
        twitter_last_updated: "2015-12-28T21:11:27.425Z",
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: 1,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 1
        },
        facebook_last_updated: "2015-12-28T21:11:29.232Z",
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 0
        },
        linkedin_last_updated: "2015-12-28T21:11:29.905Z"
    },
    {
        id: 232,
        post: "Test 944 AM http://frmply.co/1mA9G3L",
        twitter_favorite_count: null,
        twitter_retweet_count: null,
        twitter_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 5
        },
        twitter_last_updated: null,
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: null,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: { },
        facebook_last_updated: null,
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: { },
        linkedin_last_updated: null
    },
    {
        id: 234,
        post: "localhost test 1106am http://frmply.co/1RAYalE",
        twitter_favorite_count: 0,
        twitter_retweet_count: 0,
        twitter_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 2
        },
        twitter_last_updated: "2016-01-06T18:40:21.388Z",
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: null,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 0
        },
        facebook_last_updated: "2015-12-29T16:07:39.042Z",
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: {
            minute: null,
            hour: null,
            day: null,
            week: null,
            month: null,
            total: 0
        },
        linkedin_last_updated: "2015-12-29T16:07:39.489Z"
    },
    {
        id: 231,
        post: "test",
        twitter_favorite_count: null,
        twitter_retweet_count: null,
        twitter_link_click_count: { },
        twitter_last_updated: null,
        facebook_like_count: null,
        facebook_share_count: null,
        facebook_comment_count: null,
        facebook_link_click_count: { },
        facebook_last_updated: null,
        linkedin_like_count: null,
        linkedin_comment_count: null,
        linkedin_link_click_count: { },
        linkedin_last_updated: null
    }
];

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_.sortBy(results, function(item) {
  return item.twitter_link_click_count.total || true;  
}).map(function(x){return x.twitter_link_click_count.total}));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! It upvoted your answer because even though it didn't quite solve my problem, it gave me a hint (returning the item attribute or `true / 0`) that allowed me to solve it. I've updated my question above with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using plain JS filter & map

```
results = results.filter(function (a) {
    return !!((a.twitter_link_click_count || {}).total)
}).sort(function(a, b){
    return (a.twitter_link_click_count || {}).total > (b.twitter_link_click_count || {}).total
})
```

Comment: That works if I only care about the order of `x.twitter_link_click_count.total`, however that's just an attribute I want to sort my objects by.